# Why does Rust assignment of const from trait to trait not work?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to assign an associated const defined in one trait to another trait which doesn't work as expected. Here's a minimal example with 3 traits and one struct:

```rust
trait A {
    const X: i32 = 1;
}

struct S;

impl A for S {}

trait B {
    const Y: i32 = A::X;
}

trait C {
    const Y: i32 = S::X;
}

fn main() {}
```

The corresponding compiler error is:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: A`
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
10 |     const Y: i32 = A::X;
   |                    ^^^^
   |
note: required by `A::X`
  --> src/main.rs:2:5
   |
2  |     const X: i32 = 1;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The explanation for `E0283` tells me what the code reveals: I can assign from a concrete type but not the trait itself. But where the `E0283` example uses an undefined function I have an already defined value. Why is that so and how can this be bypassed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traits are supposed to be implemented by a concrete type, and are not supposed to define a constant on their own that can't be changed in implementors. What you specified is a default value, rather than a value all implementors must adhere to. You wouldn't need a trait if all types must have the same `X` value.

Therefore `A::X` is not a well defined value.

Here is an example showing why:

```rust
trait A {
    const X: i32 = 1;
}

struct S;

impl A for S {}

struct R;

impl A for R {
    const X: i32 = 42;
}

fn main() {
    println!("S: {}", S::X);
    println!("R: {}", R::X);
    println!("S: {}", <S as A>::X); // A::X alone is ambiguous
    println!("R: {}", <R as A>::X);
}
```

[(link to playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=211413bc8317973b6fae598903183d39)

What you are doing is similar to trying to call a default function on a trait, here the error E0283:

```rust
trait A {
    fn get_x() -> i32 {
        1
    }
}

struct S;

impl A for S {}

struct R;

impl A for R {
    fn get_x() -> i32 {
        42
    }
}

fn main() {
    // A::get_x() is ambiguous but there are not:
    println!("S: {}", S::get_x());
    println!("R: {}", R::get_x());
    println!("S: {}", <S as A>::get_x());
    println!("R: {}", <R as A>::get_x());
}
```

[(link to playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5223e535208dd3c02b138da0da41b1f7)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that any `struct` that implements `A` could define its own value for `X`. Thus, simply stating `A::X` in the context of `trait B` does not offer enough information for the compiler as to which `impl` of `A` should be chosen.

If you want that something that `impl`ements `B` also `impl`ements `A`, you can try the following (I have no compiler at hand, but the idea should be clear):

```
trait B : A {
    const Y: i32 = <Self as A>::X;
}
```

Comment: "I have no compiler at hand" → [Sure you do!](https://play.rust-lang.org/)